# Входные аргументы функции

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте.

Заметил одну вещь в C++, когда на одну и ту же функцию можно подавать разные аргументы, вот пример описания метода построения линии, можно задать ее объектом типа **QLine**, а можно четырьмя координатами:

```
QGraphicsLineItem * addLine ( const QLineF & line, const QPen & pen = QPen() )

QGraphicsLineItem * addLine ( qreal x1, qreal y1, qreal x2, qreal y2, const QPen & pen = QPen() )
```

Вопрос, как мне сделать свою функцию, которая бы могла принимать в качестве входного аргумента как переменную типа **int**, так и вовсе ничего?

То есть функция в **.h**

```
int myfunc(int)
```

И в **.cpp**

```
int Myclass::myfunc(int a)
{
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {...}
}
```

Задумка такова, что входной аргумент говорит, сколько раз функция должна выполнить свое действие в теле цикла, если же ничего не подаем на вход, то цикл отрабатывает 1 раз.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется перегрузка функций. Для создания нескольких реализаций в заголовочном файле объявляете свои функции, например:

```
int myfunc(int a); 
int myfunc();
```

Затем в файле .cpp реализуете функции:

```
int myfunc(int a)
{
// ...реализация
} 
int myfunc()
{
// ...реализация
}
```

С уважением, maxspb.

Comment: Пожалуй, одна из самых вредных вещей в этом языке, когда нужно разобраться с большой чужой программой.

Comment: Спасибо) я подозревал, что так и надо делать, когда читал про конструкторы классов видел несколько реализаций конструкторов таким образом в примерах) Но насчет функций не был уверен до конца)

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще вот так

```
int Myclass::myfunc(int a = 1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        {...}
    }
```